# VirtualBox faulty UI: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Gy8Y9jNtrJ: Connection refused

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, make, d-bus

I just installed Fedora 26 4.11.11-300.fc26.x86_64
 and am trying to install and run VirtualBox. Note that I had the same problems with the previous version/kernel build recently and removed the old VirtualBox packages before system upgrade/reinstallation. Here is my process (from RPM Fusion):

```
   dnf install VirtualBox kernel-devel-$(uname -r) akmod-VirtualBox
    akmods
    systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
    dmesg | grep -i vbox
[    1.057192] vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.057346] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.058094] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
[    1.077155] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 3292531211 Hz
[    1.077156] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.1.26 (interface 0x002a0000)
[    1.077492] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[    1.077705] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[    1.077939] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[    1.077942] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[  824.361468] VBoxPciLinuxLinuxUnload
[  855.368896] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
[  855.385713] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 3292471283 Hz
[  855.385715] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.1.26 (interface 0x002a0000)
[  855.386273] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[  855.387059] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[  855.387369] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[  855.387372] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
$ VirtualBox 

** (VirtualBox:18766): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Gy8Y9jNtrJ: Connection refused
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Now VirtualBox is loaded but the menus in the toolbar won't expand when clicked, and the only menus I can open, New and Settings, both have anomalous behavior in the sub-menus, e.g. can't expand context menus/drop downs. When I run as sudo everything works fine. VirtualBox in the past has never needed to run as sudo.

From here I looked at the  `/var/log/vbox-install.log` and found one error:

```
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.10.6-200.fc25.x86_64/build -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;
```

Also note that `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` executes with no output.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What gives `id`  ?

Comment: @Bahamut what do you mean? I dont understand your question

Comment: Is  your user in group vboxusers? `id` shows in which groups your user is

Comment: @Bahamut Yes, the user is in that group

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fedora, make sure that automake and autoconf is on your system, also dkms. I remember `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' ` I hope this didn't change after the years.